# Present tense and Perfective Interpretation

Tags: present-simple

I was reading about Perfective and Imperfective interpretation of a clause  Where author, Rodney Huddleston, says that '**I promise to be back for lunch**' has perfective interpretation and '**Sue mows the lawn**' has Imperfective interpretation.

He says that the first one is Perfective because 'there is a single act of promising which is performed by uttering the sentence. The act of promising and the uttering of the sentence thus occupy the same brief period of time (two or three seconds).' but not in the case of second example where it can't be considered as a single act of mowing, so it is as Imperfective one.

Now my question is that both sentence are in simple Present tense so both sentence shows indefinite time, or a routine action that has existed in past and will perhaps in future too . The act of mowing is a routine action then the same should hold true for 'the act of promising'. Then why not the act of promising In the first example is Imperfective too?

As simple present tense is used for general truth, habitual or routine action, permanent things, scheduled activities or narrating a story.

Comment: I think you might be getting confused BETWEEN [***performative utterances***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_utterance) ("To say is to do", so when you say "I do" in a marriage ceremony, you really *are* doing it by saying it), AND the [***perfective aspect***](https://www.yourdictionary.com/perfective-aspect) in English (whereby "she sat down" is "perfective" because it references a "completed act", as opposed to "she was sitting down", which simply describes an ongoing state).

Comment: Note that as my link above points out, *Since the focus is on the completion of what is expressed by the verb, [the perfective] aspect is **generally associated with the past and future tenses.*** So "I promise to be back for lunch" (Present Tense syntax with "future" implications) probably isn't a good example for helping you understand "the perfective aspect". Note also that I as a native speaker have little idea what the perfective aspect means (as yet) - the main thing I'm aware of is it's ***not a well-known term*** (my browser software insists on underlining it as "not a word"! :)